# Solving Circular Dependency infinite loop using counter?

Tags: java, loops, counter, infinite-loop, circular-dependency

I have the following 2 `methods` below.

In a correct use case `cancelChildTree()` calls `removeChildRelationsIfNecessary()` and then moves on through my code.

However for some data in my database, there is a `circular dependency` between parents and children. This is causing the 2 methods to keep calling one another in an `infinite loop`.

How can I solve this issue? My plan was to try and add a `counter` to detect that a the `infinite` loop was occurring - then move on for that particular parent child relationship.

Method 1:

```
private void cancelChildTree(Parent parent) {
  removeChildRelationsIfNecessary(parent);
  //Note that the 2 methods below never get called if the infinite loop occurs
  otherMethod();
  anotherMethod();
}
```

Method 2:

```
 private void removeChildRelationsIfNecessary(Parent parent) {
    List<Child> childList = parent.getParentChildRelationship()); 
    for (Child child: childList {
      cancelChildTree(child);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are repeatedly calling `cancelChildTree(Parent parent)` on the **same** object.

If so, what prevents you from using some `Set<Parent>` object to keep track of parent objects that were given to that method? In other words: instead of using a dumb counter; why don't you keep track of those objects that are currently processed; to avoid processing them **again**?

Comment: I have updated my code, sorry that was the old version, Copy and pasted wrong one.

Comment: My point was that you are calling that method on the **same** object all the time. And when I look at your edit, that still seems to be like that. Thus I dont get what you are trying to say with your comment here.